Notation for multiple stereotypes
Does anyone have a ref to the UML 2.5.1 where the notation for multiple stereotypes is defined?
In EA they render «s1»,«s2» while in the spec in the only example I found it's «s1,s2»
p.267 of UML 2.5.1:

On page 641

Where multiple keywords and/or stereotype names apply, the notational
options defined by 9.2.4 shall apply.

§9.2.4 states

If multiple keywords and/or stereotype names apply to the same model
element, each may be enclosed in a separate pair of guillemets and
listed one after the other. Alternatively they may all appear between
the same pair of guillemets, separated by commas.

So it appears that both «stereo1» «stereo2» as «stereo1,stereo2» are allowed.
«stereo1»,«stereo2» does not appear to be allowed by the UML specs as it only mentions the comma's in case all stereotypes are enclosed in a single set of guillemets.
Sparx Enterprise Architect (v 15.2) seems to render it correctly:


Cool. I suppose the Sparxians won't care.

Well, I'd say it's a rather small detail and actually adding the coma might even increase readability. But there we know better that such tiny details can turn the diagram meaning upside down more often than not.

@qwerty_so seems like EA was doing it correctly after all.

Yes, an unobvious fix they made somewhere in the past.
